# A function powers(n,k) that returns the list [1,n,n^2,n^3,...,n^k] where k is an integer

Tags: python, list, integer, indices

```
def powers(n, k):
    """Compute and returns the indices numbers of n, up to and including n^k"""
    b = range(k+1)
    print b
    a = []
    for i in b:
        print a  
        a.append(n**b)
    return a
```

The above code is my attempt at the problem. However it returns:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'int' and 'list'
```

So there is some problem with the n**b part of my code.

Comment: Please indent your code and also add the code that calls `powers` so we can see what the input  `n` and `k` are

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in using list comprehension, these are usually more eficient than looping through a list yourself. Also, you we're using the list your were iterating over instead of the item.

```
def powers(n, k):
    """Compute and returns the indices numbers of n, up to and including n^k"""
    return [n**i for i in range(k+1)]
```

Comment: Using ```xrange``` instead of ```range``` can improve the efficiency a bit.

Comment: `xrange` does provide some benefit, but mostly just for very large lists. As one probably doesn't want to compute very large powers using this function (k>100) there isn't too much benefit to using it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
a.append(n**b)
```

use

```
a.append(n**i)
```

Or you can simply use the `map()` function:

```
base = 10
lst = xrange(10)
result = map(lambda x: base**x, lst) # 10^0 to 10^9
```

If you're not working with floating point arithmetics (or you don't care about imprecisions introduced by rounding), you could also use incremental approach (`n^k = n^(k-1) * n`), which could be a bit faster for large arrays (while the algorithms above usually compute in `n log n`, this one would be linear).